# On re-submit of form with errors, a PATCH request is called when it's supposed to be a POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Something very funny is happening... my controller has two checks that are made separately before it allows the form to be submitted (the code below is simplistic, there are other things happening). If either checkpoint fails, the `new` page is re-rendered.

Here's the code:

```
def create
    if checkpointone == fail
        render 'new'
    else
        if checkpointtwo == fail
            render 'new'
        else
            redirect_to action: 'success'
        end
    end
end
```

Here's the funny flow problem I'm running into:

1. user enters data that fails `checkpointone` and passes `checkpointtwo`
2. user submits
3. `new` page successfully re-rendered with original parameters and error message
4. user still enters incorrect data (either `checkpointone` fails again, or it passes but `checkpointtwo` fails)
5. user submits
6. application fails with an error `No route matches [PATCH] "/requests"`

But why on earth is it looking for a PATCH all of the sudden? Who told it to? The weird thing is that if I start with a fail in `checkpointtwo` and a pass in `checkpointone`, from then on, I can make any number of fails and resubmissions in various combinations, and I'll always get the correct action: `new` page re-rendered with original parameters and error message.

Snippet of view code:

```
<%= form_for @requestrecord, :url => { action: 'create' }, :html=> {:id => 'form'} do |f| %>
```

Snippet of routes code:

```
get 'requests/new', to: 'requests#new', as: 'new_request'
post 'requests', to: 'requests#create'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 4, PATCH is used for updates. Could it be that your record is being created even when a checkpoint fails. This would cause Rails to think that the subsequent request is an update request, rather than create request.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me dig out the problem. I realized PATCH is for updates, but the additional complexity that I simplified out above left out the fact that across checkpoints one and two, there are two different models being touched. And one of them, is in fact being created, that's why it thinks it's updating.